# Minecraft server is online mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

So when I try to connect to my fav server, I get a response that looks somewhat like this:

```
Connection Lost
Exception Connecting:RuntimeException: Server Is Online Mode!...
```

I've looked up many tutorials, but I cant seem to be able to find my `server.properties` folder in order to change this. I found my minecraft folder, but I have no clue what to do from there. I'm on mac computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking about a server-side error that we can't help fix on the client-side.

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with some mod on the server side, based on the wording and odd capitalization of the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

To change the server.properties you must be the owner of the server. Otherwise this error means that you don't have the premium version of the game and thus can't connect to that premium server

Comment: wdym premium version? I payed for the game.

Comment: @Ski3s There is no "premium version" of Minecraft. If you've bought something with that name, you've been scammed. I recommend contacting your bank and trying to undo the payment.

Comment: I dont have the resources do do somethign like that. It still hasnt fixed itself.

Comment: is it possible it is server-side? it says it has 0/150 players? could this mean its down for other people too?